# How to force hardware acceleration in JQuery animations?

Tags: jquery, animation

```
$("#touchmenuwrap").hide();
$("#touchmenubutton").click(function(){
    $("#touchmenuwrap").slideToggle(200);
    });
```

How can I hardware accelerate this slideToggle and prevent flickering on mobile devices?

I came across this markup but am unsure how to implement it, if even this is what I need.

```
.webkitForceHardwareAcceleration(){
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-perspective:1000;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**SOLUTION/UPDATE:**

I couldn't find any way to reliably hardware accelerate JQuery animations so I simply found the CSS3 transition equivalent and hardware accelerated that using the 3D transition hack. It removed all flickering and sped it up by about 80-90% on touch devices but to achieve a 100% smooth animation on a touch device it appears that one has to dive into more serious web app territory because 100% smooth transitions are possible (squarespace.com being an excellent example).

Comment: Users can enable or disable hardware acceleration (if available) in browser settings, but you can't override that.

Comment: I'd expect jQuery to handle this automatically, that's the point of using a library. Maybe you need to use jQuery Mobile to get mobile-specific optimizations.

Comment: If I can't force hardware acceleration in JQuery animations would I be better off triggering a CSS animation and accelerating that?

Comment: If anything the browser or even the display driver should do that. JQuery sits way too far from the hardware to have anything to say about that (luckily!)

Comment: That was my impression too but JQuery is not a native language to the browser which explained the choppy animations. CSS3 transitions, however, are native to the browser since CSS processors are coded in C++ which means native animations which explains the smoothness.